# Can salesforce functions be released as part of Salesforce managed package on AppExchange?

Tags: salesforce-functions

Can salesforce functions be released as part of Salesforce managed package on AppExchange?

We build Salesforce package which connects to ruby application.

We want to establish some Web Sockets connection from Salesforce to that external application. Looks like this is not possible per se since Salesforce supports only Http connections.

Clients want to have something like gRPC connector. I was thinking of using Salesforce functions for this purpose, but I am not sure if Salesforce functions integration can be packaged inside a managed package and put on AppExchange. Can functions compute environment be established automatically for an subscriber when subscriber installs our package so that this is a seamless experience for subscribers?

Answer (score 10):

In a word: no. I asked Salesforce and got the answer that this is a roadmap item. Unlikely for next year either from what they said. Take a look at [this Trailblazer Community post](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000E91uISAR) and specifically the comment from Julian Duque:

> Our team is working on ISV/Packaging support and is on the roadmap for FY23, we still don’t have a specific date for it to go live

Comment: I second this.

On the partner forums they said that this was not delivered for GA of functions, and while they are looking at it, it is likely to be a 2GP exclusive :*(